# How to use sed to change references to directories?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

So I know how to use sed `-i 's/string/new-string/g' *.*` but I'm trying to change all references to a directory structure and I don't know the proper format for the command.

Example: I want to change 'myfolder/mysubfolder' to 'myfolder'.

So if there's a string in a file that says 'myfolder/mysubfolder/file.txt' I want it to say 'myfolder/file.txt'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on right track, just need to escape the `/`

```
sed -i 's/myfolder\/mysubfolder/myfolder/g' *.*
```

Comment: I figured it would be some kind of escape but didn't know if sed worked the same way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's#myfolder/mysubfolder#myfolder#g' *.*
```

I used a delimiter other than `/` to avoid having to escape the `/` in the string.

Comment: That's a good solution as well. Thanks.